# is this a new feature?

Tags: discussion

I just saw this, which I never saw before, so not sure if a glitch or some kind of upcoming feature, kind of automatic detection of low quality posts. Does anyone know?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's down to your ignored tags.

As a test I set 'ux-designer' to ignored and to grey-out any ignored tags:

[image]

[image]

So, you've got one or more of [icons](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/icons), [gui-design](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gui-design), [ios](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ios), [guidelines](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/guidelines) or [human-interface-guideline](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/human-interface-guideline) on your ignore list.

Comment: Thank you Jon, I didn't even know that the ignored tags feature existed so now I'm more curious because I never set anything to ignore. But at least now I know why that question looks like that!

EDIT: I did check my main page and saw I had HIG as ignored, that's super weird. Not only I never ignored that, that's one of my main interests!